# appending to associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I must be missing something obvious: I'm returning an **associative array** after my query runs, and for each nested array I wish to append  `$child['Is_Child'] = '0';` When I print out the `$child` array it is correct, but the `$child_participants` array does not have it appended; why?

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           $child_participants= $query->result_array();
           foreach($child_participants as $child) 
             {
               $child['Is_Child'] = '0';
             }

           return $child_participants;

         }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a reference instead of value by using `&$child`

```
foreach($child_participants as &$child)
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, `$child` is a copy of the element of the original array. You need to use a reference to modify the actual element:

```
foreach ($child_participants as &$child) {
    $child['Is_Child'] = '0';
}
```

The `&` operator makes this a reference.

Answer (score 3):

The `$child` variable as you declared it in a php `foreach` array is immutable unless you tell  php to make it mutable with the `&` operator.

```
foreach($child_participants as &$child) 
{
    $child['Is_Child'] = '0';
}
```

Comment: It's mutable, it's just not the same as the element of the original array.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are modifying `$child` as it's called, not the parent array.

You can do this:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $child_participants= $query->result_array();
   foreach($child_participants as $key => $child) 
    {
        $child_participants[$key]["Is_Child"] = '0'; ;
    }

   return $child_participants;

}
```